# create-react-app eslint error "Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have just created a new app using create-react app and eslint is giving me this error
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

i am new to react and dont know what i am doing wrong, though the app is running fine
I am using VS code editor.
How to remove this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding
  `sourceType: "module"`
To the eslint configuration

```js
// in .eslintrc.js (recommended) or .eslintrc (deprecated)
{
...
  "parserOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceType": "module"
    ...
  } 
...
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly to add that i.e where is eslint configuration file

Comment: .eslinrc file which is located in the project's folder or one of its oarent folders. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring